# Xamarin forms Android Listview issue with ContextActions and GestureRecognizer

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm writing an xamarin forms app. I have A ListView with custom cell (xaml):

```
<ViewCell>
    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
        <MenuItem Clicked="Btn_delete_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Удалить" IsDestructive="True" />
            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                 <Grid>
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="170" HeightRequest="170"  >
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Btn_fullscr_Clicked" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>

                            <Entry x:Name="EditTextPhoto" Placeholder="[Комментарий отсутствует]" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Margin="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill" FontSize="14"
                                   Text="{Binding Comment}" BackgroundColor="#44104e8b" IsEnabled="{Binding IsPreview}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
```

As you can see, I have ContextActions and a TapGestureRecognizer for my Image.
A have a bug on android: if you click on a view cell, the contextaction appears. ContextAction has to be done only on long press, as you know. But when I remove gesturerecognizer from Image, everything works fine.
Does anybody know how to workaround this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Xamarin.form (PCL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546002/xamarin-forms-how-to-add-image-list-inside-listview) use NativeListView Renderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a workaround for this issue. I added a transparent button in the same row where my image is and deleted tapgesturerecognizer. So the final code is:

```
<ViewCell>
    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
         <MenuItem Clicked="Btn_delete_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Удалить" IsDestructive="True" />
    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
         <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                     <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFit" WidthRequest="170">
               </Image>
               <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" Clicked="Btn_fullscr_Clicked" 
                                    WidthRequest="170" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" />
               <Entry x:Name="EditTextPhoto" Placeholder="[Комментарий отсутствует]" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                                   Margin="5" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill" FontSize="14"
                                   Text="{Binding Comment}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsPreview}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
         </Grid>
    </ViewCell>
```

Hope maybe it helps someone in future!